# Twig throws exception on if/else include/extends behaviour

Tags: exception, symfony, twig

Someone sucessfully implemented such part of Twig code?

```
{% if request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
    {% include ":Elements:cufor-font-replacement.html.twig" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "::layout-clean.html.twig" %}
{% endif %}
```

without seeing:

> A template that extends another one cannot have a body
>   (Twig_Node_Include(only: false expr:
>   Twig_Node_Expression_Constant(value:
>   ':Elements:cufor-font-replacement.html.twig') variables:)) in
>   ":Users:create.html.twig" at line 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to conditionally extend a template in Twig. You'll have to create another template that extend "::layout-clean.html.twig" and conditionally include it.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation about that.

On the other hand looking at this http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#making-a-layout-conditional it doesn't work for me as i can get error that request variable don't exists (passed to template and {{ request }} shows it.

Code bellow also don't work (and {{ layout }} prints ok


    {% set layout = request.isXmlHttpRequest ? "::layout-xhr.html.twig"
                                             : "::layout-clean.html.twig" %}
    {% extends layout %}

Comment: The **Request** instance should be accessible through **app.request**, but I'm not sure about that.